# Custom D-Bus monitor written in Python not receiving all messages

Tags: python, monitor, dbus

I wrote a python D-Bus monitoring tool which should receive all messages on the session bus. 
The problem is if there is **more than a single message (signals, method calls, method returns) in a short time**, I just get the **first** message. I tested this with dbus-monitor, which shows all messages on the bus.

**Here is my script:**

```
import sys
import os
import time

import dbus
import dbus.service
import _dbus_bindings
import gobject

# This creates a GLib main context which is later used by a GLib mainloop to process events that dbus-python associates with that context. 
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

def print_message(m):
    print(m)

class Input:
    def start(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        #print "Input=", self.__class__
        self.start()

        self.out.start()

        self.run_inner()

        self.out.stop()
        self.stop()

    def run_inner(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        pass

class Output:
    def start(self):
        pass

    def message_dictionary_handler(self, message_dictionary):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        pass

class Handler(Output):
    def __init__(self, message_dictionary_handler):
        """message_dictionary_handler: callable"""
        self.message_dictionary_handler = message_dictionary_handler

class Monitor(Input):
    def __init__(self, which_bus, out):
        """which_bus: "system" or "session"
        out: Output"""
        if which_bus == "system":
            self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        else:
            self.bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        self.out = out

    def start(self):
        """
        Start monitoring the bus
        """
        # Arrange for this application to receive all messages on the bus.
        self.bus.add_match_string("eavesdrop='true'")
        # Add message filter. Filter are handlers that are run on all incoming messages.
        self.bus.add_message_filter(self.msg_filter)

    def stop(self):
        """
        Stop monitoring the bus
        """
        # Remove message filter
        self.bus.remove_message_filter(self.msg_filter)
        # Remove string matching
        self.bus.remove_match_string("eavesdrop='true'")

    def message_dictionary_maker(self, m):
        """
        m: received message
        """

        dump=m
        return dump

    def msg_filter(self, abus, msg):
        """
        abus: bus session
        msg: received message
        """

        message_dictionary = self.message_dictionary_maker(msg)
        self.out.message_dictionary_handler(message_dictionary)


    def run_inner(self):
        loop = gobject.MainLoop()
        print("Press Ctrl-C to stop.")
        try:
            loop.run()
        except:
            print(" Loop exited")

    def reset(self):
        pass


out = Handler(print_message)
input = Monitor("session", out)
input.run()
```

**Messages from my monitor:**

```
dbus.lowlevel.**MethodCall**Message path: /com/mydbus/pydbus/clientserver, iface: com.mydbus.pydbus.clientserver, member: Data dest: com.mydbus.pydbus.clientserver

dbus.lowlevel.**MethodRetur**nMessage object at 0x76d582e0

dbus.lowlevel.**Signa**lMessage path: /org/freedesktop/DBus, iface: org.freedesktop.DBus, member: NameOwnerChanged, dest: (broadcast)
```

**Messages from dbus-monitor:**

```
**method call** time=1507725081.508751 sender=:1.34 -> destination=com.mydbus.pydbus.clientserver serial=3 path=/com/mydbus/pydbus/clientserver; interface=com.mydbus.pydbus.clientserver; member=Data
   string "HelloDBUSServerThisIsClient1"

**method return** time=1507725082.511337 sender=:1.31 -> destination=:1.34 serial=7 reply_serial=3
   string "Return von DBUS-Server:HelloDBUSServerThisIsClient1"

**signal** time=1507725082.557260 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.34 serial=11 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.34"

**signal** time=1507725082.558629 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=5 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
   string ":1.34"
   string ":1.34"
   string ""
```

**Another example:**

**Messages from my monitor:**

```
dbus.lowlevel.**Signal**Message path: /org/freedesktop/DBus, iface: org.freedesktop.DBus, member: NameAcquired, dest: :1.33

dbus.lowlevel.**MethodCall**Message path: /org/freedesktop/DBus, iface: org.freedesktop.DBus, member: AddMatch dest: org.freedesktop.DBus

dbus.lowlevel.**Signal**Message path: /org/freedesktop/DBus, iface: org.freedesktop.DBus, member: NameOwnerChanged, dest: (broadcast)

dbus.lowlevel.**MethodCall**Message path: /org/freedesktop/DBus, iface: org.freedesktop.DBus, member: Hello dest: org.freedesktop.DBus
```

**Messages from dbus-monitor:**

```
**signal** time=1507725076.981426 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.33 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.33"

**method call** time=1507725076.982076 sender=:1.33 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=AddMatch
   string "eavesdrop='true'"

**method return** time=1507725076.982138 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.33 serial=3 reply_serial=2

**method call** time=1507725081.489070 sender=:1.34 -> destination=org.freedesktop.DBus serial=1 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=Hello

**method return** time=1507725081.489177 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.34 serial=1 reply_serial=1
   string ":1.34"
```

Comment: Updated title of question. Changed order for headings to code first before logs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full Python 3 program which monitors notifications using the new `BecomeMonitor` call:

```py
import dbus
from gi.repository import GLib
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def msg_cb(bus, msg):
    if msg.get_interface() == 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' and msg.get_member() == 'Notify':
        args = msg.get_args_list()
        print("Notification from '%s'" % args[0])
        print("Summary: %s" % args[3])
        print("Body: %s" % args[4])

def main():
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()

    obj_dbus = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.DBus',
                              '/org/freedesktop/DBus')
    obj_dbus.BecomeMonitor(["interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"],
                           dbus.UInt32(0),
                           interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications')

    bus.add_message_filter(msg_cb)

    mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
    mainloop.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of monitoring the bus is to use the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring.BecomeMonitor()` method, rather than trying to eavesdrop on every message (which makes your code fragile, dependent on the bus config rules for eavesdropping).

See the [D-Bus specification on eavesdropping](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-routing-eavesdropping):

> Eavesdropping interacts poorly with buses with non-trivial access control restrictions, and is deprecated. The BecomeMonitor method (see [the section called “org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring.BecomeMonitor”](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-become-monitor)) provides a preferable way to monitor buses.

That might be causing certain messages to not be seen by your match filter. If that’s not the problem, then you might have something wrong with your main loop, although I can’t tell from quickly looking at it.

Overall, I have to ask why you’re trying to re-implement a bus monitor, when `dbus-monitor` already exists (and evidently works)?

Comment: I tired to re-implement a dbus monitor because i need to create a test environment for applications and their communication regarding d-bus on an embedded linux system. The plan is to transfer all the d-bus messages from linux into my existing testsystem on windows. I tried this with the python dbus-monitor above and send it over a socket to windows. Do you have other ideas for me to do this? Thx

Comment: I suggest running `dbus-monitor --pcap` on the embedded system, and transferring the pcap log files it generates to your development system for analysis with Wireshark.