# Receive a dbus system-bus method call in python

Tags: python, dbus

Apologies for the imprecise question, I am very unfamiliar with the topic and I am looking for directions on how to solve this problem. I would like to process this dbus message in python:

```
>> sudo dbus-monitor --system
method return time=1707567251.413331 sender=:1.18 -> destination=:1.7 serial=14 reply_serial=103
method call time=1707567251.509627 sender=:1.7 -> destination=:1.18 serial=104 path=/com/moonboard/service0/char1; interface=org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1; member=WriteValue
   array of bytes ",R101,R117,S176,S174"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "device"
         variant             object path "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_67_40_FA_3C_0F_C2"
      )
      dict entry(
         string "link"
         variant             string "LE"
      )
   ]
```

How do I "read it using the python `dbus` module?

Comment: What exactly is the goal of what you are trying to achieve? Is it to monitor all dbus traffic? Or are you trying to get GATT notifications from a BLE device?
There might answers already that might help you e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46688576/7721752 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/63750053/7721752